# What methods are taken to ensure that mobile web images are rendered properly in all mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile, retina-display, mobile-webkit

Using CSS, and two different instances of images, I am able to achieve the results I want to see on two different mobile devices. For devices using a screen width of 320, I implement the images as image1.png. For the newest devices, such as the iPhone4 (Retina Display) I implement the images as image1@2x.png. This requires a normal.css stylesheet as well as a hirez.css stylesheet which is called by using

```
<link href="theme/hirez.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" />
```

However, these new Amoled / Super Amoled phones are rendering these 2x images very poorly; it makes all 2x images appear pixellated.

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong... I have 2 sets of images for each filename, and calling the correct css sheet... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should simply use the high res image and display it at 50% of it's height and width on the page.

Comment: In the hirez.css I have the @2x.png images displaying with a background-size of 50% their relative image... for instance, the normal.css will be 50px width and 50px height, hirez.css will have the same, but telling the @2x.png image to stay at the background-size of 50px and 50px... i am guessing these super amoled displays are just not capable of grabbing the hirez.css when entering the website.

Comment: that's possible, maybe the pixel ratio i not 1.5 on those devices. Could you try 1.1 or something? you never know :)